# Val Function and overload notice

Tags: vb.net

in the MSDN, this is the description of **VAL()** function:

> This member is **overloaded**

What's overload property? why part of functions or methods in .NET have this property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973896.aspx):

> In an OOP language such as Microsoft® Visual Basic® .NET, you are allowed to create methods in a class that have the same name but different argument lists. Visual Basic .NET can figure out which method to call during compile based on the parameter types that you pass. This technique is called overloading a method.

[Example for VAL()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k7beh1x9(v=vs.90).aspx)

```
Public Overloads Function Val(ByVal InputStr As String) As Double
' -or-
Public Overloads Function Val(ByVal Expression As Object) As Double
' -or-
Public Overloads Function Val(ByVal Expression As Char) As Integer
```

Answer (score 1):

Function overloading allows you to have 2 functions with the same name but with different arguments.

Eg:

```
DoSomething();
DoSomething(int arg1);
```